# How to check the performance of word embedding

Tags: python, word2vec, word-embedding

I have used the gensim Word2Vec model and applied it in my list of documents. Well , the word embedding is getting created. I want to know if Word2Vec is performing well on my list of documents. Is there any metrics to measure that? How will I understand if Word2Vec has really worked well on my document corpus or should I try some different embedding?
Below is the code I have used from gensim.

```
import gensim
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(documents , size=150, window=10, min_count=2, sg=1, workers=10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no universal definition of "performing well". It depends on your end-goals.

Why do you want to create word-vectors? What value do you expect them to provide?

With the answer to those questions, you can 1st review the results in an informal, ad-hoc fashion: look at some of the words nearest-neighbors (the results of `wordvecs.most_similar(query_word)`) to see if they make sense to you, for your needs and problem-domain.

But to really test whether your models are doing better over time, as you improve your data or model-parameters, you should form some repeatable, quantitative tests that match your end-goal. (For example: do you need certain pairs of words to be closer to each other than to some third word? Do you use the word-vectors as input to some other classification or info-retrieval process that has some known,desirable results?)

Run those tests, to score the model, then compare one model's score against another.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This makes sense to me.